# What is /var/opt/mssql-extensibility in azure-sql-edge Docker image

Tags: docker, azure-sql-edge

I am running the [`azure-sql-edge`](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-azure-sql-edge) docker image like this:

```
docker run --cap-add SYS_PTRACE -e "ACCEPT_EULA=1" -e "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=<my secure password>" -p 1433:1433 --name azuresqledge -v sqlvolume:/var/opt/mssql -d mcr.microsoft.com/azure-sql-edge
```

After starting it, when I check the volumes I not only have the `sqlvolume`, but also 3 other ones:

```
C:\Users\user>docker volume ls
DRIVER    VOLUME NAME
local     41b93c39526...//name shortened
local     493c440ec34...//name shortened
local     8035ef529a3...//name shortened
local     sqlvolume
```

I don't understand why. Details for the first volume in Docker Desktop:
[image]
As we can see in the target column, it's used for `/var/opt/mssql`? But I specified `sqlvolume` for `/var/opt/mssql` when I started the container? Also, what about `var/opt/mssql-extensibility`, what's that at all?